# Orbeon - How can I prevent a component's CSS from being rewritten by the Server Side Embedding API?

Tags: orbeon

I have created a custom XBL component that includes very little markup. It primarily consists of CSS, JavaScript and a `<div>`. The JavaScript then writes the markup to the DOM, inside the `<div>`. Its CSS specifies styles for a lot of specific element IDs. This works just fine in Form Runner, but not with the Server Side Embedding API.

The Server Side Embedding API appears to be rewriting the CSS file. It prefixes all the CSS selectors for specific IDs with `o0`. For example `#MultiMousePosition-cwm` is changed to `#o0MultiMousePosition-cwm`. This might work fine if the markup of the elements were included in the XBL component. Then it could be rewritten. But since the markup is generated by JavaScript after the page is loaded, this doesn't happen.

Is the rewrite of CSS and element IDs done in case the API is used to include multiple forms in the same page?

Is there a way to prevent the CSS from being rewritten? Or is there some other way to deal with this problem?

I tried to use `<xxbl:global>` but it looks like that won't work for CSS resources.

The JavaScript is a complex library created by another developer and rewriting it to avoid this issue would take a significant amount of work, if it is possible.

Comment: Can you use CSS classes instead of ids? I assume not based on your comment that "The JavaScript is a complex library created by another developer".

Comment: I expect that is possible. I plan to discuss it with the developer when he is back in the office. This does make me wonder why you are not also renaming CSS classes as well as the IDs, since the potential for conflict is there as well.

Comment: We kind of address this as well, but in a different way: by surrounding all of our CSS definitions with a `.orbeon` class.

Comment: Thanks. I have discussed with the developer and he is updating the CSS to use classes instead of IDs. This seems like the best solution. I think using classes is considered better practice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite of ids is done to prevent id conflicts in the resulting HTML page. That can include supporting multiple forms, but also possible conflicts with other content on the page.

Currently there is no way to disable rewriting. It wouldn't be hard to add as a configuration property, possibly on the XBL components (though some things would need to be rewritten on some not, which might make the configuration more difficult), or globally, for users who know for sure they won't have id conflicts.